# IDEA does not recognize Android module in multiplatform project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I’m trying to embrace android, ios and js in one multiplatform project for my talk at the conference.
As I already described here (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29453) kotlin-frontend-plugin can't work with the Android plugin. So I commented out everything related to Android and added js part. It worked well. After I finished with js part I commented out everything related to js and uncommented android part. But now it does not recognize android in the project. I can not choose a module in Run/Debug configuration. And it shows the message “Kotlin not configured”

I can not add/setup module for android. For some reason, android sources are placed in the `main` folder but all the other sources are placed in folders prefixed by `ios` and `common` when the project is created. Later, when project synchronizes it creates a folder for each android flavor prefixed with `android`. And everything is in the same module.

How can I setup android again in the multiplatform project again?